# Passport authentication via reddit in asp net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reddit

I see [it already exists in node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-reddit) (also: [github link](https://github.com/ghaiklor/passport-reddit-token)), so I thought it must be also possible in asp.net.

The idea would be:

1. Ask the user to log in using their reddit account
2. Send them to reddit.com so they can introduce their name/password
3. Callback to my website, where the user will be identified with his reddit username

Comment: Google took me here: [reddit api oauth C# example](http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2016/10/reddit-api-oauth-c-net-example.html)

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. I know there are web apps that do it -- you might have luck messaging those devastated directly.

Comment: Ahem. *developers, not "devastated".